# Script modifications to help remove unused maven dependencies

Tags: java, ruby, maven, spring-boot, scripting

I recently came across a script https://github.com/siivonen/maven-cleanup . What this script does is it removes a dependency from the `pom.xml` , and runs a command that you mention ( preferably `mvn clean install`). And if the build is successful then proceeds on removing the next dependency , or if the build fails then it leaves the dependency untouched.

I have somehow ended up adding a lot of dependencies in my spring-boot application. My spring application consists of three service applications sharing a common service-parent. Each of these three services have their own `pom.xml` . And the service-parent has its own `pom.xml` .

I tried running the script at the service-parent level , and it successfully removed many dependencies such that my `mvn clean install` was not failing. But it removed many run-time dependencies , now I am not able to start any of my spring-application.

What I want to do is  run a command like   `./remove-extra-dependencies.rb ~/IdeaProjects/Parent-service/pom.xml 'mvn clean install && cd Child-Application-1 && mvn spring-boot:run && cd ../Child-Application-2 && mvn spring-boot:run && cd ../Child-Application-3 && mvn spring-boot:run'`

This will ensure that all removing a dependency doesn't effect any of my application's run-time. But the problem is `mvn spring-boot:run` starts the server which I cannot (AFAIK) cannot terminate using command without affecting the script's run.

Is it possible to modify the script or run a command to achieve what I want ( the aim is to remove extra dependencies which are not used ). Remember I don't want to meddle with run-time dependencies.

Comment: My suggestion is to do it manually using Maven's_dependency:analyze_ goal. This goal lists out all declared dependencies which are not used in your project. Once you have that list, you can decide which jar is needed or not needed at runtime and act accordingly.

Comment: @Ramu That is fine , but I was interested in something like this script , where I can sit back and let it do all the work.